# Remove links using myjdapi

Tags: python, jdownloader

I try to remove link that have .opus in the filename using [myjdapi](https://github.com/mmarquezs/My.Jdownloader-API-Python-Library/blob/master/myjdapi/myjdapi.py) but it fails to remove

JD API reference : [here](https://my.jdownloader.org/developers/)

Example of code that I use:

[image: jd link]

```
import myjdapi
import sys

try:
    jd = myjdapi.Myjdapi()
    jd.set_app_key("JDPeter")  # name of your choice

    # Connect using your username and password
    jd.connect("xxxx@gmail.com", "password") 

    # connection
    if jd.is_connected():
        print("Connected successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to connect.")
        sys.exit()

    # update device
    jd.update_devices()

    # print device
    print("Dispositivi: ", jd.list_devices())

    # Get the device you want to use
    device = jd.get_device("JDownloader@abc")  # Sostituisci con il nome del tuo dispositivo

    # Test your device
    if device:
        print("Device obtained successfully.")
    else:
        print("Unable to obtain device.")
        sys.exit()

    # Now you can use the various API functions. For example, to get packages from the LinkGrabber:
    packages = device.linkgrabber.query_packages([{
        "bytesLoaded": True,
        "bytesTotal": True,
        "enabled": True,
        "eta": True,
        "finished": True,
        "running": True,
        "speed": True,
        "status": True,
        "childCount": True,
        "hosts": True,
        "saveTo": True,
        "maxResults": -1,
        "startAt": 0,
    }])

    # Iterate through packages
    for package in packages:
        # Print the package name
        print("Pacchetto: ", package['name'])

        # Check the connection
        if not jd.is_connected():
            print("Connessione persa. Tentativo di riconnessione...")
            jd.connect("xxxx.com", "xxxx")  # Sostituisci con il tuo email e password
            if not jd.is_connected():
                print("Impossibile ristabilire la connessione.")
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("Connessione ristabilita con successo.")

        # Get package details
        package_links = device.linkgrabber.query_links([{
            "packageUUIDs": [package['uuid']]
        }])

        # Check if there are .m4a and .opus files in the package
        m4a_exists = any(link['name'].endswith('.m4a') for link in package_links)
        opus_links = [link for link in package_links if link['name'].endswith('.opus')]

        # If a .m4a file exists, delete all .opus files
        if m4a_exists and opus_links:
            for opus_link in opus_links:
                response = device.linkgrabber.remove_links([opus_link['uuid']], [package['uuid']])
                print("Risposta da remove_links: ", response)

except Exception as e:
    print("Errore: ", str(e))
```

The problem essentially my script lists both the packages and the names of the files within these packages, but it doesn't eliminate the names containing .opus as an extension

Comment: Maybe try `cleanup` ?

Comment: yes, no works cleanup method

Comment: And you have no errors?